When using rendering in Blender using eevee without a GPU, does lighting behave differently, or is it just calculated more slowly?
I am following this tutorial to generate a scene with a certain look and feel in the lighting and materials. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9eAVW4G8ws (The lighting and materials setup start at 8:10.) In the video, the EEVEE rendering engine is being used.
In the video, the emission material effectively lights up the metallic material that surrounds it. (See at 9:16 in the video).
However, even when I have followed the tutorial exactly, the metallic material does not receive any light from the emissive material. What's more is that the object that has been assigned the emissive material itself does not seem to have any depth to it, it just appears as a flat, blue silhouette.

I am using  EEVEE like in the tutorial. My materials are just one metallic material and one emissive blue material with a strength of 30, just like in the tutorial.
I am starting to think that maybe this is because I am using a laptop without a dedicated graphics card.
My question is, when using rendering in Blender using  EEVEE without a GPU, does lighting behave differently, or is it just calculated more slowly?
Edit:
In the Render properties panel, I found Ambient Occlusion, Bloom and Screen Space Reflections and checked all these checkboxes. The result is now like this: (Not great, but much better)



Do you try https://blend-exchange.com/ to provide your Blender file ?

@StefLAncien Ah thanks, I've uploaded the blend to there and I've updated the description.

The video is using Blender 2.81.16. Are you using the same ? In Blender 4.2.4, GPU vs CPU is available only for Cycles render engine. In EEVEE, do you check Raytracing ?

EEVEE is a GPU renderer. You cannot use it without a GPU. It can only use GPU to render, doesn't even support CPU rendering. This means it uses whatever week GPU you have and, sure it can run out of memory and stop being able to cope very quickly.

@MartynasŽiemys Thats interesting. Thing is though, I did make a render using eevee on the CPU! So does this limitation text you've linked to mean that any renders I get out of eevee by running it only on a CPU are only working due to happy coincidences, and that eevee CPU renders are therefore likely to produce very different and buggy results compared to if I ran the render with eevee running on a GPU?

@StefLAncien I am using Blender 3.0.1. I couldn't see anywhere to turn on Raytracing. But under the "Render properties" panel, I found "Ambient Occlusion", "Bloom" and "Screen Space Reflections" as checkboxes. Turning all of these on, I get a much better result. (See updated description) But its not great. I'm not sure if this is just due to the intrinsic limitations of eevee, or actually if its the result of eevee running poorly because it isnt designed to run on the CPU only.

"I did make a render using eevee on the CPU" No you did not. EEVEE only works on GPU, it does not support CPU rendering. The GPU integrated in your CPU was used. It also makes your monitor work. "Being a rasterization engine, EEVEE only uses the power of the GPU to render. There is no plan to support CPU (software) rendering as it would be very inefficient. CPU power is still needed to handle high scene complexity as the geometry must be prepared by the CPU before rendering each frame." Source

You say: "In the video, the emission material effectively lights up the metallic material that surrounds it. (See at 9:16 in the video)." No, it is not lighting up the metallic material. He just has (much) bloom activated and the light gets reflected in the metallic surfaces  (at 3:45 in the video you can see that Screen Space Reflections is enabled). Nothing is lit up by the emissive material. And the Raytracing you could not find to turn on is available in 4.2 and newer, that's what @StefLAncien was talking about, we had no information which version you were using at that point.
